# Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' does not contain WSGI application 'application'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Pulling my hair out! I am trying to deploy a Python FLask application to AWS Elastic Beanstalk and I am getting the error

Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' does not contain WSGI application 'application'

The web page is just returning a 500 Server error

the content of my application.py is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import connexion

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application = connexion.App(__name__, specification_dir='./swagger/')
    application.add_api('swagger.yaml', arguments={'title': 'This is a basic API fascade to theprotptype development robot. The API front-ends the communication with an MQTT pub/sub topic, which uses the Amazon Web Services IoT service.'})
    application.run()
```

Runs fine locally, but no good when I upload to AWS.  I have changed the name from app.py to application.py and changed the app =  to application = but no change

Don't know where to go next :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to move the line `if __name__ == '__main__'` after `application=...`, because the launcher may *import* your script instead of exec it. In that case `__name__` will not be defined as `__main__`. See this [page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-flask.html) for better example.

```
application = connexion.App(__name__, specification_dir='./swagger/')
application.add_api('swagger.yaml', arguments={'title': 'This is a basic API fascade to theprotptype development robot. The API front-ends the communication with an MQTT pub/sub topic, which uses the Amazon Web Services IoT service.'})
if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.run()
```

Comment: Thanks, that moved it forward, now it passes that and fails with 'AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'default_controller'' :) :(

Comment: Seems that your local packages have different version with those on the AWS. Check the version number of those related packages.